# syntax error near unexpected token in a case

Tags: bash, jenkins

I am trying to compare in bash using `case` (in a Jenkinsfile) a given value and act upon it. However, the `case` fails due to:

> syntax error near unexpected token `Manager'

The error happens here:

```
...
...

def microServicesList = microServicesToUpdate.tokenize(",")
...
...

for (String microserviceName : microServicesList) {
    sh """
        ...
        ...

        case ${microserviceName} in
            "Instances Manager")                               
                // do something
            ;;
        esac
    """
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to surround it with double quotes:

```
case "${microserviceName}" in
```